# PHP - manage server

Tags: php

Recently I rented a `Virtual Machine` for my experiments and works, and I would like to create a simple way for the final client to manage emails, databases, etc. So, since I'm using PHP and I'm aware that it's not safe at all to grant root permissions to it, how would you do it? Accessing bash scripts via PHP?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an awful lot of work. I would recommend using one of the already available tools, instead. One that i already used myself and therefore can recommend is [ISPConfig](http://www.ispconfig.org/).

It's implemented in PHP and open-source.

Comment: Thanks, seems nice. I will check it out, but I really need to build something new.

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like [DirectAdmin](http://www.directadmin.com/). It costs a few bucks, but saves you from having to re-write it in your own code.

Comment: I actually want to have that work, and I will just build a few functions. I can, however, use `DirectAdmin` (I have `WebAdmin` installed actually) in case it has some sort of `API` to access it's private functions or any way that doesn't involve getting to know the system UI.